# if else conditions used in drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am trying to get an alert to pop up when a certain condition is met. 
My condition is, when the div with ID's "div3" and "div4" is occupied by 
2 dragged elements with ID's "drag2" and "drag1". So both divs have to have both dragged element too. Then the alert will pop up.

Javascript code:

```
        function drop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();

    var item = document.getElementById(data);
    var targetId = ev.target.id;

    if (item.id === "drag1" && item.id === "drag2" && targetId === "div4") {
        if (item.id === "drag1" && item.id === "drag2" && targetId === "div3") {
            alert("Success");
        }

    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<img id="drag1" src="images/equation.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img  id="drag2" src="images/equation_1.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">

<div class="box" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
<div class="box" id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
```

I have tried several ways, for example putting both conditions at one go but it still won't work.

Please help.

Comment: create a snippet stating your problem. And [check](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you put a more complete code and be more specific ?

Comment: first, your code will only run once, you need to run it at each drag event, then, your code doesnt mean anything : `item.id === "drag1" && item.id === "drag2"` litteraly means : if my id is 1 AND is 2 at the same time, thus it is impossible for your code to work, try a little code first, to alert when ONE div (drag1 or drag2) is dragged into ONE container (div3 or div4)

Comment: I tried doing it that way: when drag1 is dragged into div4, an alert pops up. However, i need it to pop up only when both drag1 and drag2 is in div4 together...

Comment: I put the code under drop event so that I can detect what is being dropped at a specific div